# Explaining output of netstat -lntu

Tags: linux, networking, port

When I do `netstat -lntu` on a server running my web application, I get the list of services running on the system. I originally did this to see which ports were open.

The list I see is given below. Can you tell me why `0.0.0.0:80` and `0.0.0.0:443` are replicated multiple times in this list? My webserver is nginx, and I'm running `16` worker processes (in case this is related to that).

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::6432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6245            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::42854                :::*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each entry represents one instance of a process listening on a socket. Specifically you have 16 processes running on your web server therefore you are seeing 16 on both the secure and the non secure listeners.